# Make ctrl + backspace work everywhere

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

So I recently discovered that ctrl + backspace deletes a word and I love it. The problem is that this doesn't work in all programs. I thought that this was a Windows feature, but apparently it is something a specific program chooses to implement.

So is it possible to make this work everywhere? Like probably write a script or something, but I'm not sure where I should start.

(By the way I'm new here so if this isn't the place to post this question could you tell me where?)

Thanks.

Comment: all Windows form's text objects can capture Ctrl+Backspace so it works in all programs as long as they use the default GUI. Some apps decided to draw their own controls and hence miss a lot of Windows features

Comment: I mainly noticed this when playing games, and when using Windows Terminal Emulator. So is there a way to enable it for those? Or maybe something with AHK?

Comment: games usually use their own controls to draw text which doesn't follow any standard. I think you can use some scripting language to workaround that but only if the text can be selected and copied so that we can manipulate in the script, otherwise the only way you can do is via OCR to recognize the word which is far too expensive and less correct